# Adding Office 365 API Call Permissions to the Azure Management Console

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, ms-office, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to generate, through the Windows Azure Management Console, an API key that will allow me to make requests for Exchange Calendar Data (I need access to the Office 365 Exchange Online API set).

**I am trying to get to** [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCSPL.png) - from a [help post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666233/get-started-with-office-365-rest-api) I saw. Unfortunately, **I only have** [these options](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxqaeui3xenroc0/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-09%20at%2012.24.01%20AM.png?dl=0).

However, I don't have access to the Office 365 permissions set for the application I created, and I can't figure out how to get access. Do I have to have an Office 365 organization account?

A few more details: the application itself is in my default directory, and it isn't multi-tenant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create an application with Azure AD that uses Office permissions, I had to register for an Office 365 account with the same account that I used to create the application in the Azure Management Console. You probably won't see those permissions unless you have signed up for Office 365.

I signed up for a free trial and let it expire, and I was still able to use the requisite application permissions for Office. My Azure free trial also expired, and I was still able to use AD as I had before, and my application can still make API calls.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do I have to configure any other parts of the Management Console besides the AD page? The support articles are a little unclear.

Comment: If you're just making API calls from Office 365 products with an app that you've created yourself, no, you don't have to do anything else. Just register the App with AD, make sure you have the requisite codes (client ID and secret, etc.), and you should be good to go to make calls.